# Orange: What happened with AttributeStatistics widget?

Tags: widget, orange

I am working on some older Orange tutorials and I found some information about AttributeStatistics widget. In the current version there isn't any widget with this name. Could someone give more information about it? Is there a substitution widget? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This must had been a really old tutorial. Since the widget shows (mostly) box plots, it has been given a more proper name Box Plot. :)

Comment: Well, actually, it is a very old tutorial. Box plot is something else. I did receive today an answer from the University of Ljubljana and they gave me information that this widget is "on the making" and it will be provided very soon. We will wait and see :) Thanks anyway for your time

Answer (score 1):

As written above, the widget is "on the making" and it will be provided very soon. There is a entry in github for further reference.